# Print multiple Instance of one class using another class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a board game(Ludo) that will need 13*13 boxes. I have one box class that print out one square button and rendering it works fine. Code below:

```
class Box extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <button className="square">
        
      </button>
    );
    
  }
}
```

Problem is when I try to print multiple Box with the Board class. Apparently this code does not work. I can't figure out why. Any insight will be helpful.

```
class Board extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      {this.renderRow}
    );
  }
  renderRow(){
    for(let i= 0; i < 13; i++){
      return(
        <Box />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like even the box is not working. Only when I comment out Board class the Box class works.

Changing from {this.renderRow} to (this.renderRow) inside Board:render solved the issue where even Box class won't render(as mentioned in update 1). new code is:

```
class Board extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      (this.renderRow)
    );
  }
  renderRow(){
    return(
        <Box />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could it be `this.renderRow()` inside your `Board:render` ?

Comment: yes, definetly, @HalilÇakar. To call a function you'll need to use () inside render.

Comment: Also seems the same to me. But I can't find out where it's wrong. apparently, something is wrong inside Board class. But I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @TimGerhard Yes, your input helped. check update 2. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few problems here. Currently nothing invokes `renderRow` method + it returns single item instead of array (row). To fix single row rendering you can:

```
class Board extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return this.renderRow();
  }
  renderRow() {
    return Array.from({ length: 13 }, (_, i) => <Box key={i} />)
  }
}
```

Now we create an array with 13 boxes.

[Try on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-leftpad-zzs4u?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I was trying something like this. Any idea why it does not work?
  renderRow(){
    return(
      for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++){
        (<Box />)
      }
    );
  }

Comment: As I mentioned above, it returns single item

Comment: Works like a charm. But I don't understand this (_, i) part.

Comment: This is a map function to call on every element of the array. We don't care about the item itself, but only about index (so every box gets different key). More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Answer (score 1):

`this.renderRow()`. You're forgetting about `()`.
Also you'll find that react will start giving you errors n the console, due to lack of the `key` attribute on the Box